# std::unordered_map and std::deque complexity

Tags: c++, time-complexity, language-lawyer, unordered-map, deque

I've been reading [gcc 13537 bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13537) about std::deque push_back, push_front operations, and how they are really amortized O(1), instead of just O(1).

The discussion end with conclusion that deque's map of pointers reallocation (which is O(n)) is not taken into account for complexity of push_back/push_front, because of [[container.requirements.general]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/containers#container.requirements.general-2):

> All of the complexity requirements in this clause are stated
> solely in terms of the number of operations on the contained objects.

since moving the pointer is not an operation on the deque contained object.

So it made me think, why the same logic is not applied to std::unoredered_map::rehash?

In the worst case, all of the unoredered_map's elements can have the same hash, so they end up in the same bucket. For each element, we need to append it to the same bucket, which are most likely implemented as single-linked lists. If we are appending element to the end of the list, we need to iterate through all of its elements, so we have n O(n) insertions, O(n^2) in total. But iterating through the list should not involve any operations on unoredered_map's elements, so with the logic above applied, insert should be O(1), and the whole thing should be O(n)

This is really confusing, It looks like either deque's complexity should be stated as amortized, either rehash should be O(n) worst case, or perhaps I just don't get it right?

Edit: After reading the comments, now I dont see any reason to even go through the bucket on insert, and this O(n^2) worst case becomes even more confusing

Comment: I don't see how appending `n` elements to a linked list is`O(n^2)`.

Comment: *which are most likely implemented as single-linked lists* - what makes you think it doesn't cache a tail pointer for appends or simply appends by inserting at the head?

Comment: I think the OP means to ask why the stated complexity in the standard for the rehash operation is worst-case O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

The  question is based on an incorrect assumption, the conclusion wasn't that it was ignored but instead that the standard had already been corrected.

Following the discussion for LWG #139 (it is broken in that document)
http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#139
we see that the standard was updated to add "amortized".

Thus there is neither a defect in the standard nor in gcc as the pointer-update can be done in amortized constant time (this is part of C+11 and possibly earlier versions).

Comment: good point, but why did they leave [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/deque.modifiers#2) in the description of deque::append_range then:
_...Inserting a single element at either the beginning or end of a deque always takes constant time..._

Comment: True, it seems they aren't always clear on the difference between amortized constant time and constant time; for std::vector they even write "(amortized) constant".

Answer (score 0):

The insert operation can cause the rehash of the unordered associative containers all the elements must be inserted again in the table: it has a linear cost. This depends on both the reallocation of the underlying dynamic-size array of pointers and the insert operations that must be performed again to assign the new buckets to each of all the elements. However, the capacity increases by a growth factor on each rehash operation in order to approach the cost of an insert operation to amortized O(1).

The same is true for push operations to the `std::deque` container: if a reallocation of the underlying dynamic-size array of pointers is required, it has a linear cost. However, he capacity of the array increases by a growth factor on each reallocation in order to approach the cost of a push operation to amortized O(1).